# How can I make my text box explode with horrible characters?

Tags: twitter

Most of us just type normal text into our Stackexchange or Twitter posts. But some people are able to make their text explode from the page in horrific forms.

Eg, famously, [this Stackoverflow posting about regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4376):

[image]

Another examples is in a tweet I just saw:

[image]

I assume they're just using Unicode characters that the application doesn't know how to render properly, but I'd like to know more detail.

How is this done?

Comment: [Here you go](http://textozor.com/zalgo-text/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y̧̞̦̪̳ͦ̊̽ͨ̃͋o̥̰̜͈͚͙̮ͧ͆ͦ̀̒̓ü̷̗̬̟̬̦̖̲̋̈́̿̒ ͏̯͓̭m̢̤͕̫̺͕͍ͣ̾̒̍̆ę͎ͣ̎̌̚ͅḁ̰̞͍͙̳͆͒̊̃͐̊̐n̝̭͍̱͚̞ ̘͙ͭ̃̆ͅsͭ̊̍ͣ͗̌̚҉̝o̐ͬ̽̉͑̌̋҉m͊ͧ̅͋̆e̷̘͙̭̽̌ͧ̾͒ͫͥt̳͌ͨ̄͑h͎̞͖̯̳́̾ḭ͐n̺͚̟̼͉͇̮͑̍g̶̙̈̊ͪ̆ͪ ̬̺͓̖͇͈̹͗̑͂l͍̣ͩ̋ͫ̏̽̚ì̩̦̙͒ͫ̈́͛͊͟k̍ͨ̎ͦ̈́͢e͎̠͒̓̊͂͊̋ ̘̗̯̩͓̃ͮ̾͆ͧṭ̺̠̘̭̺ͬ͌ͨ̄h̜͚̤̱̲̎̐͟i̱̘̻ͧś̲?͈̯͓͇̟ͦ̊

-

> Basically what you have here is a bunch of alt-codes strung together in a very intricate way. I had to deconstruct this by sending it into Word and then creating a web page out of it, which gave me a series of alt-codes. By plugging in the alt-codes in Word in web-layout mode you can reconstruct or create your own "zalgo" text. By plugging in the alt-codes in Word in web-layout mode you can reconstruct or create your own "zalgo" text. You might find it easier just to copy what you find and paste it in rather than creating your own from scratch. For instance this character: ҉̵̞̟̠̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠͇ ̊ is actually a collection of alt codes strung together.
>
> To recreate it you would have to type the following:
>   alt+1161;alt+821;
>   alt+798;alt+799;
>   alt+800;alt+790;
>   alt+791;alt+792;
>   alt+793;alt+796;
>   alt+797;alt+798;
>   alt+799;alt+800;
>   alt+839

From [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090324212944AAJSyLp).

It’s called “zalgo text”. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20310289/198836) is another explanation.